# Generate lists from matrix with the same index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a matrix that has 'N' lists, each list has 3 strings, that each string has 'M' characters.

For example, N=3 (3 lists) and M=3 (all the strings are 3 characters):

```
M = [['123', '456', '789'], ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']]
```

I need to generate lists of the same index values, let me show you the output:

```
['1aA', '2bB', '3cC']
['1aD', '2bE', '3cF']
['1aG', '2bH', '3cI']

['1dA', '2eB', '3fC']
['1dD', '2eE', '3fF']
['1dG', '2eH', '3fI']

['1gA', '2hB', '3iC']
['1gD', '2hE', '3iF']
['1gG', '2hH', '3iI']

['4aA', '5bB', '6cC']
['4aD', '5bE', '6cF']
['4aG', '5bH', '6cI']

['4dA', '5eB', '6fC']
['4dD', '5eE', '6fF']
['4dG', '5eH', '6fI']

['4gA', '5hB', '6iC']
['4gD', '5hE', '6iF']
['4gG', '5hH', '6iI']

['7aA', '8bB', '9cC']
['7aD', '8bE', '9cF']
['7aG', '8bH', '9cI']

['7dA', '8eB', '9fC']
['7dD', '8eE', '9fF']
['7dG', '8eH', '9fI']

['7gA', '8hB', '9iC']
['7gD', '8hE', '9iF']
['7gG', '8hH', '9iI']
```

Do you have any suggestion how should I do it?

Comment: when `M=3` what are the characters your need show?

Comment: @KushanGunasekera that means all the strings have a length of 3, When the index is K, I need to take from each list only 1 character in index K from the string, It's hard to explain in words, but the example shows you the result for M=3

Comment: It's okay, I can understand. When `M=3` should I print some random 3 characters? Is it okay? I just confused there is some pattern your expected output.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera Umm, as a result, I need all the possible combinations, I don't really care about the order of them, but I need all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this problem is to take the cartesian product of all strings using [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and for each product, pick the items at the same index and make a string out of them using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
from itertools import product

M = [['123', '456', '789'], ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']]

output = []

#Take product of all elements
for lst in product(*M):

    #Take the characters at the same index and make a string out of them via zip
    res = [''.join(item) for item in zip(*lst)]

    #Append that list to final output
    output.append(res)

for item in output:
    print(item)
```

The output will be

```
['1aA', '2bB', '3cC']
['1aD', '2bE', '3cF']
['1aG', '2bH', '3cI']
['1dA', '2eB', '3fC']
['1dD', '2eE', '3fF']
['1dG', '2eH', '3fI']
['1gA', '2hB', '3iC']
['1gD', '2hE', '3iF']
['1gG', '2hH', '3iI']
['4aA', '5bB', '6cC']
['4aD', '5bE', '6cF']
['4aG', '5bH', '6cI']
['4dA', '5eB', '6fC']
['4dD', '5eE', '6fF']
['4dG', '5eH', '6fI']
['4gA', '5hB', '6iC']
['4gD', '5hE', '6iF']
['4gG', '5hH', '6iI']
['7aA', '8bB', '9cC']
['7aD', '8bE', '9cF']
['7aG', '8bH', '9cI']
['7dA', '8eB', '9fC']
['7dD', '8eE', '9fF']
['7dG', '8eH', '9fI']
['7gA', '8hB', '9iC']
['7gD', '8hE', '9iF']
['7gG', '8hH', '9iI']
```

Or a one-liner using list comprehension

```
output = [[''.join(item) for item in zip(*lst)] for lst in product(*M)]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `itertools.product()` and `zip()` we can group the elements we need together, then generate all the particular strings ("cell contents") from them, and then just "reshape" them into a matrix.

try this:

```py
from itertools import product

M = [['123', '456', '789'], ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']]

nums = zip(*M[0])
lowers = zip(*M[1])
uppers = zip(*M[2])
groups = zip(nums, lowers, uppers)
strings = [[''.join(chars) for chars in [*product(*g)]] for g in groups ]
string_chunks = [list(chunk) for chunk in zip(*strings)]
result = [string_chunks[i:i + len(M)] for i in range(0, len(string_chunks), len(M))]
for matrix in result:
    for row in matrix:
        print(row)
    print()
```

Output:

```
['1aA', '2bB', '3cC']
['1aD', '2bE', '3cF']
['1aG', '2bH', '3cI']

['1dA', '2eB', '3fC']
['1dD', '2eE', '3fF']
['1dG', '2eH', '3fI']

['1gA', '2hB', '3iC']
['1gD', '2hE', '3iF']
['1gG', '2hH', '3iI']

['4aA', '5bB', '6cC']
['4aD', '5bE', '6cF']
['4aG', '5bH', '6cI']

['4dA', '5eB', '6fC']
['4dD', '5eE', '6fF']
['4dG', '5eH', '6fI']

['4gA', '5hB', '6iC']
['4gD', '5hE', '6iF']
['4gG', '5hH', '6iI']

['7aA', '8bB', '9cC']
['7aD', '8bE', '9cF']
['7aG', '8bH', '9cI']

['7dA', '8eB', '9fC']
['7dD', '8eE', '9fF']
['7dG', '8eH', '9fI']

['7gA', '8hB', '9iC']
['7gD', '8hE', '9iF']
['7gG', '8hH', '9iI']
```